# Unit Testing Express Application

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, express, pug

Currently trying to learn how to write unit tests for an Express application (not integration testing/PhantomJS).

Is there a way to split up the routes into testable methods that return .json data to be rendered by the actual:

```
app.get('/route', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('template', {
    data: data
  });
});
```

Of everything I have read, they are testing the JSON output because they designed their app in a RESTful manner, whereas most of these starter tutorials are fully templated/rendered on server (which I don't think is bad), returning html to the client.  However, this is the part I do not understand **how to separate and test.**

Next is to learn backbone so the app is just tossing JSON, but for now, any suggestions or **links to complete tutorials**?

Much appreciation.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this question please?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to deal with this

- you can separate, the routes between standard site or `/api/..` for JSON responses
- you can detect what the request accepts by checking `req.accepts` [req.accepts](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.accepts) to determinate what the request accepts and output json or render html..
- you could write an output middleware which does the above checking but the middleware before that in middleware stack, should call `next()` and pass `req.responseData` and handle `req.responseData` JSON accordingly, either render or output..

for testing i recommend this module https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent passing the `accept` header or querying the right url, but JSON output would allow you to test your api without using html parsers to parse the HTML. If in case you want to test how the HTML is rendered, either use `cheerio` or phantomjs but i would try to avoid that.

As for backbone, there are plenty tutorials around, and http://backbonejs.org/ is your starting point.